# failed to open stream : no such file or directory in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-6

I am trying to upload images in to database, but getting error of failed to open stream : no such file or directory.
But when i am uploading images in App/http/controller inside the directory then it is possible to upload image, but when uploading in App/Import controller file then getting this error.
What is a good process to quickly find the solution?
i m going this way :

```
 $filenamewithextension = $image->getClientOriginalName();
 $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
 $extension =  getClientOriginalExtension($image);
 $filenametostore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
 $filePath = 'direcory/' . $image;
 Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, fopen($image, 'r+'), 'public');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YDXZ.jpg)

Comment: In which line does the error appear? What does `getClientOriginalName` and `getClientOriginalExtension` do?

Comment: it just return file name with and without extensions